# Compile Delphi 2010 Project with MSBuild

Tags: delphi, msbuild, continuous-integration, delphi-2010

I am trying to compile a Delpho 2010 project using the msbuild tool. Unfortunately when firing the command

```
msbuild Delphi.dproj
```

it returns the error code MSB4040, which means that there is no target in the project.

So far a RAD Delphi 2010 environment is still installed on the machine. Does anybody know which files do I need to compile the project without the RAD environment installed?

Thanks in advance
Dennis

Comment: possible duplicate of ["ERROR MSB4040 There is no target in the project" when using msbuild+Delphi2009](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342859/error-msb4040-there-is-no-target-in-the-project-when-using-msbuilddelphi2009)

Comment: The one with the batch file worked fine for me. What about the RAD environment contraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need following files to get Delphi 2010 compiling process run without RAD Studio installed:

The complete lib folder including the Indy10 folder (if you want to use Indy)

```
lib
lib\Indy10
```

And the following files from the bin folder

```
bin\Borland.Build.Tasks.Common.dll
bin\Borland.Build.Tasks.Delphi.dll
bin\Borland.Build.Tasks.Shared.dll
bin\Borland.Globalization.dll
bin\CodeGear.Common.Targets
bin\CodeGear.Delphi.Targets
bin\DCC32.EXE
bin\lnkdfm140.dll
bin\rlink32.dll
```

I hope this is the minimal set of needed files.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found out that you have to call `msbuild` from the project-folder instead of the installation folder of `msbuild`.

...where calling

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>msbuild D:\\...\TestProject.dprj
```

would throw some strange errors, calling

```
D:\\...\\TestProject>msbuild TestProject.dprj
```

would work fine for me.