# Finding path to MSBuild on any machine

Tags: batch-file, msbuild, cmd

I need to use msbuild from a .cmd file to build my solution.

Of course it seems to be installed in different directories on different machine setups, using  from the cmd, how can I find the installed path to msbuild.exe?

Answer (score 2):

On my scripts I always use this path:
%windir%\microsoft.net\framework\vxxx\msbuild.exe

(replace xxx with the framework desired version number).

or you can follow "the hard way": read the install location from the registry: [Path to MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328017/path-to-msbuild)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -nologo -latest -property installationPath > temp.txt
set /p $MSBUILDROOT=<temp.txt
del temp.txt

"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -property installationVersion > temp.txt
set /p $MSBUILDVER=<temp.txt
del temp.txt

set $MSBUILDPATH=%$MSBUILDROOT%\MsBuild\%$MSBUILDVER:~0,2%.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
```

$MSBUILDPATH should be you MsBuild full path.

Answer (score 0):

This works with newer versions that use 'Current' instead of version.

```vb
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Locating msbuild.exe
set VSWHERE="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe"
for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%i in ('"!VSWHERE!" -nologo -latest -property installationPath') do SET "MSBUILDROOT=%%i"
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('"!VSWHERE!" -property installationVersion') do SET "MSBUILDVER=%%i"
set MSBUILDPATH="!MSBUILDROOT!\MSBuild\!MSBUILDVER:~0,2!.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
if not exist "!MSBUILDPATH!" set MSBUILDPATH="!MSBUILDROOT!\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe"
if not exist "!MSBUILDPATH!" set MSBUILDPATH="!MSBUILDROOT!\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe"
echo Found MSBuild at !MSBUILDPATH!
```