# WiX Heat: Pre-build event fires too early on build server

Tags: msbuild, wix, heat

I'm harvesting a directory for my Visual Studio solution.

It works on my local system so far probably because the project build order is being respected.

When I run the installer on a build server it finds the right directory but it has not been created at the time of building the setup file. It throws a `HEAT5052` error saying `The directory 'a:\b\c' could not be found`.

Is there any way to "wait" until or to execute the heat command after all project references are built?

Comment: Did you check whether the quoting of your directory is correct on the server? Any whitespace in your path perhaps?

Comment: Yes but that wasn't the problem. Check my post below for the answer.

Comment: I have been encountering the same problem; I have been able to solve it by setting an explicit build order to make sure that the setup project is truly built last. (Right-click on the project in Visual Studio, select “Build dependencies->Project dependencies”, and in the “Dependencies” page of the dialog check all projects.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

OK so I've spent hours to figure out how to fire `Heat` AFTER all references are resloved. I only found solutions for the `<PreBuildEvent>` and `<PostBuildEvent>` using the `Heat` command line and the `BeforeBuild` and `AfterBuild` targets.

So I found all kind of targets inside the `wix2010.targets` file located in my
`Program files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Wix\` folder. It contains a target called `AfterResolveReferences` and it does exactly that. So here's my code I ended up with (in case someone is interested):

```
<Target Name="AfterResolveReferences">
    <HeatDirectory
        ToolPath="$(WixToolPath)"
        OutputFile="Product.Binaries.wxs"
        SuppressFragments="$(HarvestDirectorySuppressFragments)"
        Transforms="Filter.xslt"
        Directory="$(HarvestFolder)"
        DirectoryRefId="MY_FOLDER"
        ComponentGroupName="Binaries"
        GenerateGuidsNow="true"
        SuppressRootDirectory="true"
        SuppressRegistry="true"
        PreprocessorVariable="var.App.TargetDir">
    </HeatDirectory>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Would you happen to know how can I glue my hair back to my head after having torn it out trying to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was solved by combining the accepted answer and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51446250/4856020) to ensure that my post build event, which was copying files, always runs:

```
<RunPostBuildEvent>Always</RunPostBuildEvent> 
<DisableFastUpToDateCheck>true</DisableFastUpToDateCheck>
```

Also, my build server was using the MSBuild command line, and I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49047791/4856020) to locate my local MSBuild.exe so I could test my changes locally without having to push to the build server.

Comment: Officially supported way to locate MSBuild (answer written by me): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319707/70345