# Where is MSBuild.exe installed in Windows when installed using BuildTools_Full.exe?

Tags: .net, msbuild, windows-server

I'm trying to set up a build server for .NET, but can't figure out where MSBuild.exe is installed.

I'm trying to install MSBuild using the Microsoft Build Tools 2013:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

Comment: did you try "where msbuild" at the command line? note I'm assuming - quite possibly incorrectly - that it is added to the path

Comment: when I'm searching the C drive for MSBuild.exe, I only get paths to MSBuild.exe in C:\Windows. According to this on MSDN, MSBuild should be in Program Files: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh162058.aspx

Answer (score 56, accepted):

MSBuild in the previous versions of .NET Framework was installed with it but, they decided to install it with Visual Studio or with the package BuildTools_Full.exe.

The path to MSBuild when installed with the .NET framework:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework[64 or empty][framework_version]

The path to MSBuild when installed with Visual Studio is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild[version]\Bin for x86

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild[version]\Bin\amd64 for x64.

The path when BuildTools_Full.exe is installed is the same as when MSBuild is installed with Visual Studio.

Comment: The program "Everything" helped me to find it just search "msbuild.exe" it will list each and every file with that name on your PC together with the path.

Comment: Also, you can use "where msbuild" in Developer command prompt

Answer (score 67):

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/what-s-new-in-msbuild-15-0

> MSBuild is now installed in a folder under each version of Visual Studio. For example, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild`. You can also use the following PowerShell module to locate MSBuild: [vssetup.powershell](https://github.com/Microsoft/vssetup.powershell).
>
> MSBuild is no longer installed in the Global Assembly Cache. To reference MSBuild programmatically, use NuGet packages.

Comment: this path may also be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin` if you are using the Community version

Comment: When installed from "Build Tools" package the path is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

Comment: For 2022 Enterprise, I found it here: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

Answer (score 40):

Open the Microsoft command line. I'm using Visual Studio 2019, so my command line is "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019".

Then run the command (the [`Where-Object` Powershell command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.3))

```
where msbuild
```

And the path will be echo'd.

Or try this (the [`where.exe` program/executable](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html))

```
where.exe /R C:\ msbuild
```

More [here](https://superuser.com/a/1397265/292784) on the difference between:

- `where` Powershell alias /`Where-Object` Powershell command  vs
- `where.exe` executable

Comment: What if you get nothing as an answer?

Comment: @JariTurkia try `where.exe msbuild` instead if using powershell.

Comment: This worked for me: `where.exe /R C:\ msbuild`

Answer (score 19):

You can find the VS2019 here : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me (this searches msbuild.exe in c:\ - the default didn't work)

```
where /R c:\ msbuild.exe
```

Answer (score 5):

For MsBuild 17:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

For MsBuild 16:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin`

For MsBuild 15:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild` (or replace 'Enterprise' with 'Professional' or 'Community')

Comment: Visual Studio 2022 (MSBuild 17) is 64 bit, therefore the location of which is in Program Files not "Program Files (x86)"

Comment: as per Jawad, found VS 2022 at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin

Answer (score 1):

I find it here

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64
```

for `64bit` version.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a big dump of possible places, to save a few minutes' searching

Dotnet SDK from stand-alone installer:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.406\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.406\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.203\MSBuild.dll
```

From Visual Studio installer:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\core\msbuild.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd\core\msbuild.bat
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
```

JetBrains Rider self-installs:

```
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\JetBrains\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
   C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\JetBrains\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe
```

Old "Framework"

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\MSBuild.exe
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```