# Accessing and running Developer PowerShell using a Python Script

Tags: python, visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to create a python script to automatically run unit tests in Visual Studio. One path that I am exploring would involve using shells, in particular [Developer Powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019). I am running into a roadblock with accessing this shell, though. Here's what I have so far:

- First off, the Visual Studio solution has all of the necessary files; I just need to build and run, which I can do in **Developer Powershell** using the following lines

```
> MSBuild.exe .\project.sln
> VSTest.Console.exe .\x64\Debug\project.dll /Logger:trx
```

- To get to Developer Powershell, I can type the following into a normal **Powershell**:

```
> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -noe -c "&{Import-Module """C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll"""; Enter-VsDevShell 64375397}"
```

- And if I need to start from **CMD** for some reason, I can get to Developer Powershell by simply typing this:

```
> %comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"
```

My issue is trying to put all of this in a python script. I can open Developer Powershell using os.system, but then I can't use os.system again until I exit Developer Powershell. Is there a way to let the python know that I am in a new shell and to start interacting with that one?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out, but I'll just leave this all up in case anyone has a similar question:

MSBuild and VSTest.Console are both just .exe files, and as such just have their own locations that you can target in a shell (links on where to find the are below).

[MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44567280/where-is-msbuild-exe-installed-in-windows-when-installed-using-buildtools-full-e)
[VSTest](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/3541)

If you just run `> & "C:\<The_path>\MSBuild.exe"`, it'll work fine with the arguments above. No Developer Powershell needed.

You can even use [this stack exchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1724693/find-a-file-in-python) to generally find the .exe files on any Windows system.