# ResolveComReference task could not be loaded

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Win7, VS2017, ASP Net core app, target framework is 4.6.

When I try to build my project with CLI (it is needed before dotnet commands calling) the error occurs:

> C:...\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2547,5): error MSB4062:
>   The "Microsoft.Build.T asks.ResolveComReference" task could not be
>   loaded from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the
>    declaration is correct, that the assembly and  all its
>   dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
>   that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework .ITask. [C:\project.csproj]

I have been looking for questions related with my issue and have done the following things:

- restart VS
- clean and build the project with VS tools (it was successfully)
- load Microsoft.Build package
- remove content of packages folder and reload it

But nothing helps me.

What it can be?

Comment: when you write "build with CLI", do you mean the `dotnet` cli ? (e.g. `dotnet build`)

Comment: @Martin Ullrich, yes, this errors occurs when I using CLI command like 'dotnet ef migrations add qwe'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

COM references are not supported by the .net core version of MSBuild which is what the .NET CLI uses. For those references to work, you have to build your project using msbuild directly. Using the Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio 2017 you should be able to perform the build using commands like:

```
msbuild /t:Restore
msbuild /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release
msbuild /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release
```

(you can also add `/m` to enable parallel builds).

This reference is also unsupported when running CLI tools that use these project  files since they also rely on the .NET Core version of MSBuild.

However, there is a workaround that will enable CLI tools to be able to use the project, but it will not allow them to fully build using the .NET Cli. Add the following `Condition` attribute to your `ComReference` items to "hide" the COM reference when building with the .NET Core version of MSBuild:

```
<COMReference Include="FooBar" Condition="'$(MSBuildRuntimeType)' != 'Core'">
  <Guid>{some-guid}</Guid>
  <!-- a lot more metadata elements -->
</COMReference>
```

Comment: Thank, Martin, your answer is very helping for me. I opened my <project>.csproj file and found some com references there (COMReference sections). Just removing those sections is a solution

Comment: Probably depends on whether or not your project actually needs those COM references..

Comment: Relevant [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/3986).

Comment: this just gives me compilation errors for the missing types instead

Comment: @MartinUllrich Thanks, after much of hardwork finally I did by editing project file and commenting the  ommRef.. secion

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, this helped me.. i saw the COMReference block and I commented them out...

Now my App builds and works well...

Been battling with this for a while

Comment: Thanks for answer. One thing to note: You don't strictly need the "Developer Command Prompt for Visual Studio", you can just fix the path to msbuild.exe and build it from any command prompt. I found the msbuild path using this answer and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53319707/350384

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, non of answers in internet helped to fix it. Finally I installed Visual Studio on Server and I saw in Error List that a nuget package is missing! (Missing assembly error), although the nuget package was present.

Then I Uninstall and Install the nuget package and the error went away. I went in GitChanges to see what has changed, and I saw, in .csproj file, the reference to that nugetpackage which supposed to be in another folder was wrong.
Reinstalling that nuget package using VS fixed the address.