# Jenkins setup for Xamarin Forms app on MacOSX

Tags: xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.forms, continuous-integration

I am trying to setup a Jenkins job for Xamarin.Forms app. I have added the MSBuild plugin to my Jenkins configuration and am trying to configure the MSBuild location.

I tried to add this Path:`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Commands/xbuild` to MSBuild location but the Jenkins dashboard is showing this warning:

[image]

What is the exact path for the MSBuild? how can I fix this warning?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/328017/path-to-msbuild seems like a duplication of this question.

Comment: That link is for windows only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`msbuild` and `xbuild` are located here `/Library/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Commands` on a Mac.

I was running Jenkins on a Mac and did this:

- Path to MSBuild:`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.Framework/Commands`
- Name: msbuild (don't think this part matters, it is just the name you can call it anything you want.)

like so:
[image]